# Bash newline doesn't print

Tags: bash, newlines

I would like to output results in latex table format using a bash script. However, when I want to add a newline symbol, bash either prints it (\n) or doesn't add a newline. I already tried several things (e.g. the ones mentioned https://superuser.com/questions/154936/echo-text-with-new-line-in-bash), but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
echo "$(cat $outputFile)$latexString" > $outputFile
echo "\\\\" >> $outputFile
echo "" >> $outputFile
```

`$latexString` is the line of the table I want to save, `\\` is the EOF for the line in the table, and after that I want to have a newline.

EDIT The output file should look like:

```
res1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
res2 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
...
```

'latexString' is then e.g.,

```
res1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "newline symbol"? Do you want to add a literal `\n` to your LaTeX file? Isn't `\\ `already the "newline symbol" in LaTeX?

Comment: I want to print several latexStrings on different lines. Each line needs to have `\\\` at the end of the line. So it cannot print `\n`, but needs to put the content on separate lines instead.

Comment: It might be better if you provided the last line of `$outputFile` and what `$latexString` is. There might be better way of approaching this.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: What is the use of the first `$(cat $outputFile)` ?

Comment: By `echo "$(cat $outputFile)$latexString" > $outputFile`, do you mean `echo "$latexString" >> $outputFile`?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: @MaVe This is likely to truncate `$outputFile`. Why aren't you using `>>` instead?

Comment: Since I thought that was a good way to append the string to the output file. It didn't truncate the file though. But I guess @choroba suggestion is better then. How can I then still add `\\\` at the end of each line?

Comment: Each of the commands you have posted will print a newline (`\n`) at the end of the line. You will have the `\\ ` on a line by itself, is that the problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is

```
echo "$latexString\\\\" >> $outputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

`printf` will do the trick:

```
printf "%s %s\n" "$latexString" "\\\\" >> $outputFile
```

or even more readable:

```
printf "%s %s\n" "$latexString" '\\' >> $outputFile
```